# How can I set the crond for docker?

Tags: linux, docker, cron

I installed cron and

```
FROM python:3.9.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat && apt-get install -y ftp && apt-get install -y cron
```

log in the docker image

```
root@ip-172-31-12-132:/usr/src/app# which ftp
/usr/bin/ftp


root@ip-172-31-12-132:/usr/src/app# ps -aef | grep cron
root      1386   764  0 02:15 pts/1    00:00:00 grep cron
```

no `cron` is running

```
root@ip-172-31-12-132:/usr/src/app# crontab -l
no crontab for root
```

I guess I have to do something to start cron server.

```
root@ip-172-31-12-132:/usr/src/app# service crond start
crond: unrecognized service

root@ip-172-31-12-132:/usr/src/app# /etc/init.d/crond start
bash: /etc/init.d/crond: No such file or directory
```

How can I do this??

Comment: A Docker container only runs one process; tools like `service` or `/etc/init.d` scripts don't really work inside a container.  The easiest approach is to run cron in a separate container from your application, and the linked question describes several setups to do that.

Comment: THank you very much I will make another container which works for cron

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I made  another `container` in `taskdifinition` and try to invoke `container` from `eventbridge`. However I can choose only `taskdifinition`, not `container` my `taskdifinition` has three `containers` such as `django/nginx/ftp` I want to invoke only `ftp` container , is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
apt-get install cron
```

and then run

```
/usr/sbin/cron
```

Comment: it says `run /usr/sbin/cron` `bash: run: command not found`

Comment: Sorry, typo from me :-)

Comment: Thank you very much It can help when using normal container. in this case , I wan to use in fargate aws.

Comment: Have you tried above commands ?

Comment: Sorry, I am now trying another way for David Maze suggested. Your opinion. also helps. let me check around.

Comment: I'm also interested to know how it behaves in fargate aws.